# csv import with dataimporthandler solr

Tags: search, csv, solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I am trying to use solr with DIH to index csv files.
I've patched my DIH library using patch SOLR-2549 mentioned on the solr wiki (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Configuration_in_data-config.xml-1) in order to import csv files without using Transformers along with LineEntityProcessor.

Unfortunately, I could not get my import work and I have the following error stack:

```
INFO: [csv] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import&optimize=false&clean=true&commit=true&verbose=true} status=0 QTime=33 {deleteByQuery=*:*} 0 33
7 nov. 2012 14:16:03 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
GRAVE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:273)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:382)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:448)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:429)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:413)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:326)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:234)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:542)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:411)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.LineEntityProcessor.initDelimitedOrFixedWidth(LineEntityProcessor.java:142)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.LineEntityProcessor.init(LineEntityProcessor.java:115)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:74)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:430)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:498)
        ... 6 more
```

I think it's related to my data configuration.
This is my data-config.xml file:

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="dfs" type="FileDataSource"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="sourcefile"
                processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
                fileName="rocinter.csv"
                rootEntity="false"
                baseDir="/user/xxx/work/solr/example/example-DIH/solr/csv/inputfolder"
        >

            <entity name="entryline"
                    processor="LineEntityProcessor"
                    url="${sourcefile.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    rootEntity="true"
                    dataSource="fds"
                    separator=","
            >
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Could anybody help me undestand this issue or provide a clear config file using patched LineEntityProcessor version to import csv files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v finally got an answer from the user mailing list.
Actually that was a bug in the patch.

A newer version of the patch is attached to jira issue.

see: [SOLR-2549](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2549)